# How can I adjust a div and an iframe at the same time when you click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I am creating a website with wordpress and have inserted a flight search, and I am trying to adjust a div and iframe like this:

For example if you find 100 flights, the height of the div and the iframe will be 500px, if you press the button "View more results" the div and the iframe will be 200px more (500px+200px), if you press the button again the div and the iframe will be 200px more(500px+200px+200px)... all of this with the mainpage scrollbar.

My div code and iframe code are this:

```
<div class="content-area">
    <iframe src='http://www.dohop.com/widget/2/?forms=flights&target=&tabs=top&orientation=horizontal&border_color=808080&text_color=202020&background_color=D0D0D0&form_border_color=808080&form_text_color=000&form_background_color=FAFAFA&width=1000&flang=es&whitelabel=http://vuelos.gangatravel.es/' scrolling='yes' width='1000' height='250' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow: hidden;' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
   <div style='text-align: right; width: 1000px; display:block; margin-top:5px;'>
     <a href='http://www.dohop.com' style='font-size:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#007BA4;'></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

My web site is: http://gangatravel.esy.es/vuelos/ to see my problem easily

Thanks!!

Comment: Which div are you talking about?

Comment: <div class="content-area">